# What is called session store?

Tags: java, php, web-services, jakarta-ee

What is called session store in context of web applications/websites ?

Is it anything more than a temporary store of session variables?

Comment: Data stored that will be deleted once the browser is closed?

Comment: yes that data is stored in session variables ofcourse, but what exactly is session store? Is it something more than a temporary store...this is what I am clear about !

Comment: in context of what platform exactly? I expect this has different meanings on different platforms.

Comment: I read somewhere about implementing a session store using Java technology and Cassandra(NoSQL) database..

Comment: The term "session store" usually refers to how the $_SESSION variables are stored server-side. PHP usually creates files in the temporary folder for that, and marshalls the data using serialize() and some binary header IIRC. As you can have multiple session cookies, there might be multiple storage backends, and saving variables into the database is quite common too. Not sure if the temporariness has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically the user's first request to the site establishes a session.  The session has a key which is passed to the user as a cookie, so that with every subsequent request the same session is retrieved.

The session store can store information about that user you don't want (or can't due to the length limit of cookies) to put in a cookie, for example the currently logged-in user ID or the contents of a shopping cart.  This is usually in the form of some kind of serialized data structure depending upon the language/framework in use.

The reason why you might implement the session store in an external database rather than within the local web server would be to account for if you have multiple web servers in a pool; this way if the user's first request went to server A, and the next went to server B, your web app can still retrieve the same session data every time.

Comment: Does it become a neccessity with multiple web servers ? do all web apps that are based on multiple web servers are required to do that?

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple servers behind a load balancer, you need to have a shared session store of some form.  Otherwise, if each server maintains its own session store, the user will experience inconsistent behavior between pageviews, ajax requests, etc.