# Redis + Devise configuration confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, redis, sidekiq

I recently integrated my Rails webapp with Redis/Sidekiq. After playing with a ton of configurations, I realized I may have messed something up because I can no longer login to my application. After referencing this question: [Devise: Suddenly cannot log in anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071622/devise-suddenly-cannot-log-in-anymore) I figured it has something to do with my config/initializers/session_store.rb, but I suppose because I'm unclear with how exactly that file operates it's difficult for me to debug this error.

Here's the actual error message when I try to login with good credentials:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::SessionsController#create
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"controllers"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is my session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_appname_session'
AppName::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, servers: "redis://localhost:6379/0/session"
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :controllers
  devise_for :users 
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

Referencing this link: [What is called session store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868667/what-is-called-session-store) I'm aware that a session store is just storage for session information, but I'm not sure how that translates into this devise error.

I do also have the proper devise initializer file and in my config/environments/development.rb I have

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

as per the docs.

Devise Initializer:

```
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com' #haven't yet had the need to change this
  config.secret_key = 'secret_key'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.password_length = 6..128
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Controller 'controllers'--> This is a real oddity for me. I have no recollection of making this myself and I'm not sure whether it was a byproduct of some other process I followed but somehow ended up in my application. Found below:

```
    class ControllersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_controller, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /controllers
  # GET /controllers.json
  def index
    @controllers = Controller.all
  end

  # GET /controllers/1
  # GET /controllers/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /controllers/new
  def new
    @controller = Controller.new
  end

  # GET /controllers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /controllers
  # POST /controllers.json
  def create
    @controller = Controller.new(controller_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @controller.save
        format.html { redirect_to @controller, notice: 'Controller was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @controller }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @controller.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /controllers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /controllers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @controller.update(controller_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @controller, notice: 'Controller was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @controller }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @controller.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /controllers/1
  # DELETE /controllers/1.json
  def destroy
    @controller.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to controllers_url, notice: 'Controller was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_controller
      @controller = Controller.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def controller_params
      params.require(:controller).permit(:Reminder)
    end
end
```

Would appreciate help on debugging this error!

Comment: Do you have anything like `ControllersController` within your app/controllers? Also could you post your Devise initializer?

Comment: I added this info in the post above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to config your session_store to use redis.

Secondly, you config it twice in `session_store.rb`.

I suggest you use gem `redis-rails` to config redis easily: https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails

Comment: Hi Maverick,

Thanks for the input. I'm actually using redis-rails in my application and pulled the session_store config from the gem's wiki:

MyApplication::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, servers: "redis://localhost:6379/0/session"
https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails

Do you mind elaborating what exactly I did wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: It's no need to config ```session_store``` twice, just use either ```cookie_store``` or ```redis_store``` and can you tell me what is ```resources :controllers``` in your ```routes.rb```, can you remove it?

Comment: When I removed the resources:controllers and the redis_store line, it all worked. Not sure what exactly went wrong, but thank you for the help!